# Nginx unable to connect

Tags: nginx, localhost

I am referring to this link to install Nginx on Ubuntu: [Installing Nginx With PHP5 (And PHP-FPM) And MySQL Support (LEMP) On Ubuntu 13.04](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-nginx-with-php5-and-php-fpm-and-mysql-support-lemp-on-ubuntu-13.04).

`sudo su` — Runs OK.

```
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client 

mysql-client is already the newest version.
mysql-server is already the newest version.
```

Yet when I try `http://localhost` on Firefox it does not show the welcome page. (That is Nginx is not running).

> Unable to connect
>
> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.

Comment: Just checking the obvious: have you installed and started `nginx` as described in step 3 in the linked article?

Answer (score 4):

Do have a look at the port number used by nginx. Most of the times, if another web-server was installed (e.g. apache standalone, or lamp) and improperly removed, the default port 80 will be occupied.

Best bet is to first check if the port number is occupied by using
["netstat" to check the presently using ports.](https://serverfault.com/a/14438)

```
netstat -antp
```

If 80 is occupied, then try the following

1. open `nginx.conf` and change the server port number to 8080
2. save and exit
3. restart nginx by:

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart or /etc/init.d/nginx restart
   ```

Check if the above is working and do the necessary changes later.

Comment: Good explanation, I was expecting the same!!